# Function that help to remove user account

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Are there any functions in kernel32.dll, user32.dll, advapi32.dll or in some other .dll that can remove a local user account from the Administrators group?

Comment: With great power, comes great responsibility.
Carefully debug the usage of this function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [NetLocalGroupDelMembers()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370439.aspx), which resides in `netapi32.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is [NetGroupDelUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370427%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from Netapi32.dll:

```
NET_API_STATUS NetGroupDelUser(
  __in  LPCWSTR servername,
  __in  LPCWSTR GroupName,
  __in  LPCWSTR Username
);
```